# Как изменить цвет фона у ttk.Notebook в Python 3 (GUI)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, style, style-guide

хочу изменить цвет фона (по дефолту серый ) пробовал через style но безуспешно, а изменить через Configure получилось некорректно.

Код:

```
#import
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import BOLD
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFont,ImageDraw
from tkinter.ttk import Style

#Global file road
os.chdir('D:\XXXXXX')

class App:                                                              
    def __init__(self, window):                                          
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)                                  
        notebook.pack(fill='both', expand='true')  
        
        #Stiles
        Mybackground = "#0B1623"
        MyGreen = "#336666"
        MyYellow = "#F2C84B"

        test = Style()                                                            
        test.theme_create( "my_tables",  parent="alt", settings={
                "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 0, 2, 0] } }, 
                "TNotebook":     {
                    "configure": {"background": Mybackground }},
                "TNotebook.Tab": {
                    "configure": {"padding": [80, 1], "background": MyGreen }, 
                    "map":       {"background": [("selected", MyYellow)]} } }) 
        test.theme_use("my_tables")

#Main window
window_main = Tk()
window_app=App(window_main) 
window_main.title("F&S Main")
window_main.iconbitmap('Main.ico')
window_main.geometry("1200x700+200+70")
window_main.resizable(False,False)                                                   
window_main['bg'] = '#0B1623'   
                                                     
#open window_main
window_main.mainloop()
```

[image: Вывод программы и конкретно что нужно изменить]

Comment: Но вы же туда наверняка вставляете какой-нибудь frame на весь таб. Почему бы на настраивать цвет у него?

Comment: Да, @GrAnd совершенно верно я тоже так подумал и написал такой код:

`self.msg1 = Label(TAB1, background='#0B1623')
        self.msg1.pack(fill='both', expand='true')
        self.msg2 = Label(TAB2, background='#0B1623')
        self.msg2.pack(fill='both', expand='true')
 `
Однако, при переключении вкладок (если не очень медленно переключатся) пробликивает  белый фон. Пока решить не удалось (

Comment: Попробовал добавить `"TFrame":     {"configure": {"background": Mybackground }}` в тему и добавить табы с фреймом `f = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(f, text="Test")
        f = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(f, text="Another test")`. У меня при переключении вроде ничего не блинкает. Пробовал под Виндами.

Comment: @GrAnd, Спасибо огромное. Ваш совет помог. Добавил ваш код в раздел стилей и все стало четко!

Answer (score 1):

Решение, полученное совместно с [@GrAnd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338888/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83-ttk-notebook-%d0%b2-python-3-gui/1339095#comment2370238_1338888):

```
test = Style()                                                            
        test.theme_create( "my_tables",  parent="alt", settings={
                "TFrame":     {"configure": {"background": Mybackground }},
                "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 0, 2, 0] } }, 
                "TNotebook":     {
                    "configure": {"background": Mybackground }},
                "TNotebook.Tab": {
                    "configure": {"padding": [80, 1], "background": MyGreen }, 
                    "map":       {"background": [("selected", MyYellow)]} } }) 
        test.theme_use("my_tables")
```